# How to enable disabled chrome console log output in Zkoss?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, zk

In Zkoss .zul file I have something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="true">
        console.log("logging into chrome dev. tools console");
        zk.log("throw ZK console output");
    </sctript>
```

Logging trow Zk work good, but doesn't work console.log("logging into chrome dev. tools console") it doesn't show up. Do you have any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
delete console.log;
```

Comment: I meant absolutely another